# Python combine derived classes to the same base class?

Tags: python, class

Say I have a base class `Person` and two derived classes `Footballer` and `Musician`.

Obviously a person can be both a footballer and a musician, so maybe I want a third class called `FootballerAndMusician`, but this class will just be a combination of the two other classes (there will *not* be conflicts: the two derived classes only override some specific things, and nothing in `Musician` overrides that which is overriden in `Footballer`, and vice versa).

What is the appropiate way to implement this pattern in Python that avoids having to repeat the code in the two derived classes in a third class (Imagine if I had to do this with several classes…)?

Basically, I want to implement many derived classes to `Person`, and then easily be able to combine them as long as there aren't conflicts.

How is this designed in Python?

Answer (score 2):

This is called Multiple Inheritance, and in Python this looks like this

```py
class FootballerAndMusician(Footballer, Musician):
  # your specific class code goes here, like
```

Now that class gets access to all the methods of both of the superclasses.

There's some subtle complexities with the order in which methods are looked up. In this simple case, though, it's just "left to right". So if both `Footballer` and `Musician` have a method called `play` then in the example above your `FootballerAndMusician` would use the `Footballer` version.

Note that multiple inheritance can get complex and messy quickly, so you should really use it sparingly. I would suggest *avoiding* it if it's just in order to create some big "taxonomy".

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
class FootballerAndMusician(Footballer, Musician):
    pass
```

This assumes, of course, that both `Footballer` and `Musician` (and `Person`) are correctly designed to allow for multiple inheritance. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using `super` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is what you're looking for.

```py
Class Base1:
       (body_1)

Class Base2:
     (body_2)

Class Derived(Base1, Base2):
     (body_3)
```

As long as your Base classes `Footballer` and `Musician` don't interfere with the other's methods, you're good to go.
Additionally, if you need to explicitly use the constructor,

```py
Class Derived(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(Derived, self).__init__(args)
```